# How to force nginx proxy_next_upstream with Node.js Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

I have a Node.js Express server deployed via nginx proxy_pass. I have two paralell daemons on different ports loadbalanced using upstreams. The initialization of Express server takes time, so I send Error 500 until it is ready. And I want the nginx to use the other upstream server until the first one is ready and vice versa.

I tried to use proxy_next_upstream, but it is not working well. There is always at least one Error 500 that is displayed to the user.

Maybe the reason is hidden in the following sentence from nginx doc: "One should bear in mind that passing a request to the next server is only possible if nothing has been sent to a client yet."

Here is the proxy_pass configuration:

```
proxy_pass   http://node_servers ;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $remote_addr;
proxy_read_timeout 60;  proxy_connect_timeout 60;
```

These are the upstreams:

```
upstream node_servers {
    server 127.0.0.1:12005;
    server 127.0.0.1:12006;
}
```

And this is how I send the Error from Node Express:

```
res.status(500).send('The server is not ready yet!');
```

Answer (score 2):

You must configure nginx to use next server when "error 500" is received.

By default, nginx uses next server on "connection error" and on "timeout" only, so you must tune your configuration:

```
   proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500;
```

"Use the docs, Luke!" 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream

Comment: I used proxy_next_upstream, but even then it doesn't work. I suspect the Express to send something before the error and therefore it gets to the user.

Comment: and use tcpdump to assert your suspection